# How to recover messages in queue with ActiveMQ if my application breaks?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm new to `ActiveMQ`. I have 2 `queues`: `parser-queue` and `generation-queue`. My application is running in **2 different servers**, both are **listening** to the queues. My workflow is quite simple, get the message from parser-queue, process it and put another message in the generation-queue when the job is done.

However, if during my job process, get the message and process it, my application is shutdown, or it breaks for any reason.

How can this same message, that wasn't processed correctly, can be sent to my queue again in order to be processed ?

I'm reading about [Subscription Recovery Policy](http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html) but it seems a very complex subject, and I'm not sure if I want to use a policy based in time, since my jobs can vary in time to be completely processed by my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should disable auto acknowledge feature in your JMS consumer. In that case the message will not be consumed until the client confirms it.

If you are using Spring, then it can be done like this:

```
<bean id="myJmsConsumer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="MY_QUEUE"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myJmsListener"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionListener"/>
</bean>
```

More on JMS transaction can be found here: http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/08/20/spring-book-chapter-17-messaging-with-spring/11/